# External javascript file not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript that's loading just perfectly at the bottom of my site. I wanted to externalize this aforementioned js, so I'm now linking to the code externally, but now the code breaks and is pointing to an error (not within the js file but the jquery file).  What changes when the js is externalized? Are variables retrieved in the same way?

Thanks

Comment: There's very little help that can be given if you don't show some sort of code.  However, the first thing I'd check is to make sure you included your document load callback $(function() { ... });

Comment: You need to add some details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably added the `<script>` tags in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

you can probably use firebug and see whats happening there.
there is net panel which shows whethere that particular js is downloaded propery or not.
after that you can see the errors on the console window of firebug to find what exactly is the error.